# Столкновение не по прямоугольникам в Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Я делаю 2D-игру (платформер). Добавил в землю склон, но так как spritecollide() работает только по прямоугольникам-хитбоксам, то герой как бы парит в воздухе.

Вопрос: как сделать столкновение не по прямоугольникам в pygame, желательно без других модулей (но если других решений нет, пишите своё)?

Answer (score 2):

Имею костыльную идею. Предлагаю хитбокс разделить на несколько более мелких хитбоксов. Примерно также это работает в 3д шутерах. Этот метод не даёт чистое столкновение по пикселям(только если на каждый ряд пикселей делать хитбокс). Это должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
def hitboxcollide(hitboxes,ygroup):
    ifcollide = False
    for box in hitboxes:
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(box,ygroup):
            ifcollide = True
            break
    return ifcollide
```

- `hitboxes` - хитбоксы
- `ygroup` - группа (это Pygame объект) элементов, с которыми может
  столкнуться хитбокс.
- `ifcollide` - булевое значение на вывод из функции (по аналогии со
  `spritecollise`)

Я не проверял моё решение и тем более не знаю как выглядит ваш код, поэтому тут определённо требуется доработка. Более того решение костыльное, ибо сама идея простая, но есть очень много условностей в исполнении.

Comment: Прикольно, долго, конечно, но работает. Плюсик ваш

Comment: Пока не ставлю галочку, потому что, возможно, есть еще короче решение

Comment: @alex9127 спасибо.

Comment: @Cof.Cof., можно и без переменных и `break`: `def hitboxcollide(hitboxes,ygroup):` `for box in hitboxes:` `if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(box,ygroup): return True` + `return False` (в конце функции)  :)

Comment: @gil9red, вы знаете, что вы предлагаете ту же самую идею, только под другим соусом? На фиг вы это писали?

Comment: @alex9127, такое ощущение, что мой комментарий другому пользователю с **рефакторингом кода**, задел лично вас :) Объясняю, идея такая же, но код проще за счет того, не используется ненужный флаг и вместо выхода из цикла, а после выхода их функции сразу выполняется выход из функции с нужным значением. Все, что я написал это рефакторинг и если его не делать, когда это нужно, то код станет трудночитаемым

Comment: @gil9red в моей вселенной рефакторинг кода - это преобразование длинных кусков кода в функции, дабы код стал удобочитаемым. Я в первый раз вижу, чтобы кто-то убирал булевую переменную и называл это рефакторингом XD

Comment: @gil9red, я не подумал, что после return код не выполняется. Спасибо!

Comment: @alex9127, то, что вы описали похоже на правило не повторяйся (Don't repeat yourself), рефакторинг имеет более широкое действие, например берем сложение строк в `__repr__` при описании класса `Dog`: `print('<Dog name=' + self.name + ' type=' + str(self.type) +  ' paws=' + str(self.paws) + ' has_tail=' + str(self.has_tail) + '>')`, я бы отрефакторил с форматирование строки: `print(f'<Dog name={self.name} type={self.type} paws={self.paws} has_tail={self.has_tail}>')`. Как видите, код стал читаемым, рефакторинг.

Comment: @gil9red понятно